# Line of Symmetry of the Zeta Function

Tags: riemann-zeta, symmetry

I heard once that 0.5 is the line of symmetry of the Riemann Zeta Function. What does that mean? A graph illustrating would be helpful.

Comment: It means that values with $\Re(s)<1/2$ are fixed by the values with $\Re(s)>1/2$ due to the functional equation.

Comment: So for example zeta(0.6+14i) is equal to zeta(0.4+14i)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_Xi_function \\
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function

Comment: I don't read German.

Comment: The symmetry comes more into light using the $\Xi$ function which is an even function.

Comment: So my earlier statement is true then as 0.4=1-0.6

Comment: $\zeta(0.6+14i)$ is related to $\zeta(0.4-14i)$.

Comment: Oh you're right I forgot about the imaginary part But are they equal or related?

Comment: related...look up functional equation in the links and you'll see.

Comment: So, with the Riemann Xi function, is there a single value assigned to everything before the Riemann Zeta Function part (ie from the 1/2 to the gamma function)

Comment: What do you mean by single value? The prefactor is a function too, but a well understood one.

Comment: What I really want to know is if zeta(1-s)=zeta(s). If not, then what is?

Comment: We have $\xi(s)=\xi(1-s)$ (not $\zeta$). Now I would like to know what you need this for? You are new, what is your background?

Comment: Oh, I'm just studying the Riemann Zeta Function, specifically it's symmetry because I believe there is something within it. I'm also studying how to factor large semiprimes quickly using polynomials and ratios.

Comment: Also, is there any value, z (in terms of s), for zeta(s), that zeta(z)=zeta(s). If not, is there a proof why?